# Android: arrayList de Bitmaps

Tags: java, android, array

Como genero un arraylist de Bitmaps en mi setter setImages, busque algunos ejemplos pero solo encontré el siguiente ejemplo

Mi código

```
public class CheckIn {
private int folio;
private String customer;
private String delivery;
private ArrayList<Bitmap> images;

public int getFolio() {
    return folio;
}

public void setFolio(int folio) {
    this.folio = folio;
}

public String getCustomer() {
    return customer;
}

public void setCustomer(String customer) {
    this.customer = customer;
}

public String getDelivery() {
    return delivery;
}

public void setDelivery(String delivery) {
    this.delivery = delivery;
}

public ArrayList<Bitmap> getImages() {
    return images;
}

public void setImages(ArrayList<Bitmap> images) {
    this.images = images;
}
}
```

Ejemplo que encontre

```
public class City {
protected int id;
protected String name;
protected String data;
protected Bitmap photo;

public City(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(String data) {
    this.data = data;
    try {
        byte[] byteData = Base64.decode(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
        this.photo = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray( byteData, 0, 
            byteData.length);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Bitmap getPhoto() {
    return photo;
}
```

}

El ejemplo solo settea un bitmap en setData pero yo tengo no solo una imagen sino varias

Comment: he agregado una respuesta de como sería en ambos casos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a el ejemplo que encontraste:

Defines el Array que contendrá los Bitmaps:

```
ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArray = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
```

entonces agregas cada Bitmap a tu Array:

```
public void setData(String data) {
    this.data = data;
    try {
        byte[] byteData = Base64.decode(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
        this.photo = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray( byteData, 0, 
            byteData.length);
        //Agregas cada Bitmap a tu Array:
        bitmapArray.add(this.photo);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

---

En el caso de tu código original:

```
    //Defines tu ArrayList
    ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArray = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

   //Método para obtener el ArrayList de Bitmaps.
    public ArrayList<Bitmap> getImages() {
        return bitmapArray;
    }

    //Al almacenar un Bitmap este será agregado a el ArrayList de bitmaps el cual será obtenido por getImages().    
    public void setImages(ArrayList<Bitmap> images) {
        this.images = images;
        bitmapArray.add(images);
    }
```

Comment: gracias Elenasys tome parte de tus ideas

Comment: @Javierfr Que bien Javier, la segunda parte es la que se usaría en tu código para crear un Array de Bitmaps.

Comment: Si Elenasys perdon por estarte fastidiando mucho porque eres de los que mas me responden, ya mero termino mi aplicacion android ya estoy en la conexion con el web service

Comment: :3 gracias ....

Comment: @Javierfr al contrario no fastidias, es bueno saber que pronto terminas tu proyecto! ᕕ(◔_◔)ᕗ

Answer (score 1):

Tu lista `ArrayList<Bitmap> images;` tiene el metodo `add`, para agregar uno o más elementos a tu lista simplemente llamas `images.add();` Como tu tienes muchos `Bitmap`, puedes recorrerlos si es que los tienes previamente en un arreglo o bien, agregarlo uno a uno si sabes cuales son. En este caso recorrer el arreglo `tuarreglo` que vendrian siendo todos tus `Bitmap` y los agregas a tu `ArrayList`.

```
CheckIn checkin = new Checkin();
ArrayList<Bitmap> images = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
//recorrer los BitMaps y los agregar a tu arraylist
for(int i = 0; i < tuarreglo.length ;i++ ){
   images.add(tuarreglo[i]);
}
checkin.setImages(images);
//o tambien checkin.images = images;
```

Comment: Gracias sioesi estoy checandolo